# Array conversion from string to int crashes the browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an array of strings to an array of integers in javascript. I saw the following solution in a coupple of threads here and in a couple of other sources so I fuigure it must be correct, however when I get to the conversion the browser crashes. I have tried with Chromium and Firefox.
Here is the source code, I am interested in what is causing this and what can be fixed:

```
 var str = "1,2,3,3,4,5,6";
 var arr1 = str.split(",");
 console.log(arr1);
  for(var k=0; k<=arr1.length; k++) { arr1[k] = +arr1[k]; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this expression

```
k<=arr1.length
```

When `k` is `6`, `k++` increments `k` and it becomes `7`. And then `k <= arr1.length` is true because `arr1.length` is 7. The next statement is

```
arr1[k] = +arr1[k];
```

which creates a new element in the array at index 7. So the array keeps on growing infinitely. What you should have done is

```
var arr1 = "1,2,3,3,4,5,6".split(",");
for (var k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
    arr1[k] = +arr1[k];
}
console.log(arr1);
# [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Iterate only till the counter is lesser than length of the array. Otherwise store the length of the array in a temporary variable like this

```
for (var k = 0, len = arr1.length; k < len; k++) {
    arr1[k] = +arr1[k];
}
```

You can write the same as, simply

```
console.log("1,2,3,3,4,5,6".split(",").map(Number));
# [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: Also it is always better to save array length in the variable before actual iterations for not checking the length in each pass.

Comment: You are correct. It's a very stupid mistake. I hadn't noticed the extra "=" unitl you pointed it out. It took me a good amount of time looking too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the given answer, you may want to use this oneliner to create the array:

```
var arr1 = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'.split(',').map(function(a){return +a;});
```

[**MDN page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for `Array.map`